# Save only if value is not empty Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Does anyone know if its possible to make sure that Rich text content control object is filled? and if not the file will not be saved?

Code is embedded in a word document not a module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
    Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim richTextControl1 As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.RichTextContentControl
    
    If richTextControl1.Value = "" Then a = MsgBox("File not saved fill Approval ID field ", vbInformation)
    
    If a = vbInformation Then Cancel = True
Else
End Sub
```

This is what i got for now. The code seems to refer correctly to the context control element(when trying to format the text it spits out the code in the field) but apart from that nothing else happens. Any help or direction appreciated

Comment: `Workbook_BeforeSave` is for Excel not Word. Are you trying to write code for Word or Excel?

Comment: Its a word document. Its a template to fill out for approval for SOP. I know how to do it in excel but word is a little bit different and i want to avoid creating a whole Word document generator from excel.

Comment: In that case I suggest you write your code in Word and make use of Intellisense, the Object Browser, and online help <kbd>F1</kbd>.  You'll find it helpful to look up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.showingplaceholdertext  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytag  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.selectcontentcontrolsbytitle  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentbeforesave